# References in C - making changes to data using an alias

Tags: c, reference

I have a buffer containing data at specific offsets. Since the buffer is a block of variable-sized data segments, I must access each segment using defined offsets. It would be very convenient to create a reference to each data segment in the buffer and make modifications directly. The closest I have been able to get to such an implementation is the following:

```
#define OFFSET_VAR1 0
#define OFFSET_VAR2 (OFFSET_VAR1 + sizeof(int))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t buf[sizeof(int) + sizeof(short)] = {0}; 

int main(void) {
    short *var2 = (short *) (buf + OFFSET_VAR2);
    *var2 = 5; 


    printf("Value: %hd\n", *var2);
    printf("Value: %hd\n", (int) buf[OFFSET_VAR2]); 

    return 0;
}
```

However, something like this would be more along the lines of what I am interested in:

```
int &var2 = *((short *) (buf + OFFSET_VAR2));
var2 = 5;
```

I know C++ has a similar construct, but can this be done in C? I know this could be accomplished through the use of macros, but I would like to avoid such an implementation for access scope reasons.

```
#define var2 *((short*) (buf + OFFSET_VAR2))
```

Comment: No, C doesn't support references like that; you're stuck with using a pointer.